# What is the meaning of the word 'out' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The jury is still out on whether the strategy will work.

Comment: A jury leaves the courtroom when all the evidence has been presented, and stay 'out' of the courtroom until they have arrived at a verdict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a jury has heard the arguments in a court trial, it goes "out" to the private room where it deliberates.  While the "jury is out" the parties in the trial are waiting suspensefully for the verdict.

The phrase "the jury is out" is thus used as a metaphor for a situation where some decision or critical piece of information is awaited.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I read this word from Reuters. The line was - Trump is eschewing such traditional “retail politics” in favor of large, high-profile rallies and television appearances.

The jury is still out on whether the strategy will work.

Comment: @user152621 - Yep.  That means that it's still unknown whether his strategy will work.

Comment: Thank you sir, now I understand the meaning of the sentence.